# Find $[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{3}+ 2^\frac{1}{3})} : \mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: ring-theory, extension-field

Find :

$a.[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{2}})} : \mathbb{Q}]$.

$b.[\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{3}+ 2^\frac{1}{3})} : \mathbb{Q}]$.

My attempt:

$a. x= (\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{2}}) \implies x^2=3+ \sqrt{2} \implies x^4-6x^2+7=0 \implies [\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{3 + \sqrt{2}})} : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$

b.$x=\sqrt{3}+ 2^\frac{1}{3}$ , I try to get a minimal polynomial $p$ such that $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i=0$ , such that $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Is $(a)$ is correct (I am not entirely sure that this is the right wat to solve this problem) ?

Any idea how to solve $(b)$ ?

Comment: You need to show that these polynomials are indeed monic and *irreducible*.

Comment: @UmeshShankar thanks but how to find the polynomial of (b) ?

Comment: For (b): It is easier to show that $Z := \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}, 2^{1/3}]$ is an extension of degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Further, $L:= \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}+2^{1/3}]$ is a subfield of $Z$, so $[L:\mathbb{Q}] | [Z:\mathbb{Q}]$. Thus, $[L:\mathbb{Q}]\in\{1,2,3,6\}$. However, $1,2,3$ are not possible (why?), so the only option is that $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 6$.

If you want to find an explicit minimal polynomial for (b), check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276188/for-alpha-sqrt32-i-find-the-minimal-polynomial-over-mathbbq-an?rq=1

Comment: Alternatively, solving a system of equations gives you $m(x) = -23-36x+27x^2-4x^3-9x^4+x^6 $ as a minimal polynomial

Comment: Let $a=\sqrt {3},b=2^{1/3},c=a+b$ and show that both $a, b$ are rational functions of $c$ so that both $\mathbb{Q} (a) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(c) $ and $\mathbb{Q} (b) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(c) $ and hence $c$ is of degree at least $6$ over rationals. Next find a polynomial of degree $6$ with rational coefficients of which $c$ is a root.